# What is wrong with using $(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S") in a cron job?

Tags: bash, cron, backup, cron-task

I am trying to sumbit a MySQL backup script through cpanel cron jobs panel, but I am receiving errors that I don't understand.
I have tried the command on my Ubuntu

```
mysqldump -u(USERNAME) -p(PASSWORD) --all-databases | gzip > /home/MYHOMEDIR/myDBBckups/full_backup$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").sql.gz
```

The error I am facing is:

```
---------- Email message ----------

From: Cron Daemon <root@MYSERVER>

Date: Thu, Jul 11, 2013 at 9:37 PM

Subject: Cron <MYUSERNAME@MYSERVER> mysqldump -u(USERNAME) -p(PASSWORD) --all-databases | 
gzip > /home/MYHOMEDIR/myDBBckups/full_backup$(date "+

To: MYEMAIL@gmail.com


/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file 

---------- End of Email message ----------
```

When I remove the date command everything works fine but I don't want to override my backup every time.

With help of Colleagues, i fixed it like this:

```
mysqldump -u(USERNAME) -p(PASSWORD) --all-databases | gzip > /home/MYHOMEDIR/myDBBckups/full_backup$(date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S").sql.gz
```

many thanks.

Comment: The double quotes (`"`) in the title are correct, but they're rendered as opening (`“`) and closing (`”`) quotes, at least in my browser (and the opening and closing quotes look identical in the font used for comments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `%` character in the command portion of a cron job is translated to a newline character. Either use `\%` to denote a `%` character, or put the `date` command into an external script that you invoke from `cron`.

Answer (score 1):

[Cron interprets the % character.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Special_characters)

Put the line in a file `create_backup.sh` and put the command `bash /path/to/create_backup.sh` in your crontab instead.

Comment: Of the special characters mentioned on the linked web page, only `%` is relevant; the others are not treated specially in a command.